# SMTP connection from localhost

Tags: exim

Since a few days ago I have been seeing recurrent SMTP connection from localhost each few minutes or so when checking /var/log/exim_mainlog

```
2015-05-08 13:34:41 SMTP connection from [127.0.0.1]:48724 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2015-05-08 13:34:42 SMTP connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:48724 closed by QUIT
2015-05-08 13:35:29 cwd=/etc/csf 2 args: /usr/sbin/exim -bpc
2015-05-08 13:39:44 SMTP connection from [127.0.0.1]:48748 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2015-05-08 13:39:45 SMTP connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:48748 closed by QUIT
2015-05-08 13:40:29 cwd=/etc/csf 2 args: /usr/sbin/exim -bpc
2015-05-08 13:44:48 SMTP connection from [127.0.0.1]:48774 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2015-05-08 13:44:49 SMTP connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:48774 closed by QUIT
2015-05-08 13:45:29 cwd=/etc/csf 2 args: /usr/sbin/exim -bpc
2015-05-08 13:49:50 SMTP connection from [127.0.0.1]:48800 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2015-05-08 13:49:51 SMTP connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:48800 closed by QUIT
2015-05-08 13:50:29 cwd=/etc/csf 2 args: /usr/sbin/exim -bpc
```

Seems a connection is started then stopped one second after.
Anyone knows what can cause this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the regularity (5 minutes) and the correlation with the `exim -bpc` invocation (which checks the mail queue status), my guess is it would be some kind of monitoring probe (nagios plugin, or something of that kind) that checks if your SMTPd is healthy.